# IntelliJ IDEA code inspection highlighting faulty visibility errors

Tags: java, intellij-idea, package, visibility, code-inspection

So, I've got this problem - a strange problem. I have a library as part of an IDEA project - in which all the code is publicly visible under 'tk.*' (IE: all classes exist in sub-packages of tk). Should the attempt be made to import a class residing within that package IDEA highlights the import statement (only th 'tk' mind you - which is strange enough), citing the reason mentioned later. Despite the apparent "errors", the project (consisting of a formidable number of files) compiles successfuly - very much so, infact.

Info:

- The highlight reason (when you hover over the aforementioned highlight): 'tk' is not public in ''

  - Note about this: the file importing from said package IS NOT in the default package.
- It would seem that the importing from packages residing in other libraries is not found at fault by IDEA
- The class(es) imported by aforementioned file(s) are not package-private, nor protected, nor private - they are public
- The project's path settings should be correct, however I am open to the suggestion that these may be at fault

Notes:

- Sorry if this quiestion reads wierdly - I'm rather distracted by the environment in which I currently reside.

Comment: Try `File` | `Invalidate Caches` and make sure `tk` directory is not added to the libraries in the dependencies of the modules.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I'd forgotten about that, thanks for reminding me. But, alas, that doesn't work.

Comment: Please share a sample project to reproduce so that we can verify that your dependencies do not reference `tk` directory.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I'll put one together. In the process of that, I can see if the problem is reporoduced.

Comment: @CrazyCoder This is odd, the error is not occurring - I'll compare the structure of the two

Comment: @CrazyCoder The problem appears to have been caused somehow by another library in the project